# How to use foreach() on list of string and assign values to a refence variable based on a conditional stament

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test1","test2","test3","test4");`

I want to achive something like this:

```
String cCN = "";
boolean flag = true;
list.forEach(ele -> {
    if (ele.equals("test3")) {
        cCN = ele;
        flag = false;
    }
});
```

This is not allowed since lambda expression can only access effectively final or final variables.
IDE suggests using AtomicRefrence for this, but I was thing if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: The intended behaviour is unclear. Are you looking for the first instance of "test3"? Is the flag supposed to serve any purpose other than being false if the list contains "test3"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is considered as a bad practice to write lambdas that have heavy side effects as your example. Correct way to do it using stream API would be using *filter* function like:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test1","test2","test3","test4");

Optional<String> cCN = list
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> s.equals("test3"))
        .findFirst();
```

It is generally considered a bad practice to use side effects in Java Stream API operations. Stream operations should be designed to produce output based solely on their input, without modifying any external state.
Stream API is designed to allow for functional-style processing of collections or arrays of data.

One of the key features of functional programming is that functions should be pure, meaning that they should not have any side effects and should only rely on their input arguments to produce output.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the expression to a simple findFirst:

```
 String cCN = list.stream().filter("test3"::equals).findFirst().orElse("");
```

If you needed those variables you should save the `Optional<String>` result and declare as:

```
Optional<String> find = list.stream().filter("test3"::equals).findFirst();
String cCN  = find.orElse("");
boolean flag= find.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a `String[] cCN = new String[] {""};` and then use `cCN[1] = ele;` in your code instead.

The more general point here is, lambdas are just worse here. Lambdas are non-transparent in 3 regards:

- Control flow; you cannot `break` e.g. a while loop that is declared outside a lambda, from inside one. Nor you can `return;` the outer method from within a lambda.
- Checked exceptions: A checked exception thrown by code inside a lambda cannot be caught outside of it, unless the thing you passed the lambda to (`.forEach`, here) explicitly goes out of its way to make that possible, and most lambda-taking methods in the core libraries didn't.
- Local variables. You cannot modify a local variable declared outside a lambda, from within it.

All 3 are **good** things when the lambda 'travels' (continues to exist and could be called after execution has long passed the lexical context where it was created. For example, when you pass a lambda to something that then stores it in a field to call it later, or passing a lambda to code that ends up firing up a new thread / handing the lambda on to code that will execute it in a different thread). Because all 3 are 'weird' in that case.

But they are just annoying when the lambda doesn't travel, and `.forEach()` lambdas do not travel.

Conclusion: Do not use lambdas here. Calling `.forEach(ele -> ...)` is, effectively, **always wrong**. Because it is inferior to using `for (var ele : list)`, which can do everything `forEach` can, and 3 more things on top of that - namely the 3 transparencies named above.

`.forEach` is designed for when you already have a lambda. Imagine you have a method that already has access to some `Consumer<String>` for some reason, for example because it was passed in via parameter, and you want to apply that consumer to a list. Write `list.forEach(theConsumer)`, instead of `for (var ele : list) theConsumer.cosume(ele);`.

Comment: regarding the first point: A stream does the equivalent of `break;` as long as you use the correct terminal operations. For instance, .findFirst() would terminate the stream before processing the next element, making the result nearly equivalent. It's subjective, but a stream could have a huge advantage of readability if written neatly compared to a native for-loop.

Comment: regarding the third point: The inability to mutate variables is mostly a mechanic which pushes the user towards writing cleaner code with immutable variables. If you find that you need to mutate variables in a stream, you either have thread safe options through atomic variables, or you might be better of rethinking your code.

Comment: @ODDminus1 you didn't understand the notion perhaps. I'm talking about `break;`ing not the `forEach` itself, but a loop outside of it. `for (String foo : bar) { x.forEach(() -> { .. you cannot break the foo:bar loop here ...}`.

Comment: In regards to _huge advantage of readability_ that is a preposterous claim, and with entirely no support provided. "Readability" is hard to define, but, surely, `foo.forEach(x -> code())` cannot be "hugely more readable" than `for (var x : foo) code();`, given that other than shuffling a few nodes around they are nearly identical. Your hyperbole ('huge'!) suggests you are trying to peddle a personal preference with prejudicial arguments. Please refrain from doing so, there are more than enough hotheaded holy wars in programming as is.

Comment: "Clean code" is a similar weaselworded malarkey. What is clean code? Generally it is defined as "everything this _obviously proven to be problematic_ code is not", i.e. it's defined as a no-true-scotsman logical fallacy. And thus, useless, as a tool to attempt to argue in favour or against any particular code style. Yet again I implore you, cut it out with the dressing up of your personal preference with entirely subjective ideas couched in terms that sound objective even when they aren't.

Comment: I'm countering your hyperbole of "Calling .forEach(ele -> ...) is, effectively, always wrong." I heavily disagree with this baseless statement, and I'm therefore stating that opening up to using the method could result in code which is *subjectively* cleaner. Java is continuously moving towards functional-style code, where practices of using immutability and functional interfaces is often recommended. Your answer attempts to firmly regard functional style code as a very narrow functionality of java, and I deeply disagree with that.

Comment: @ODDminus1 “practices of using immutability and functional interfaces” are great but using `forEach` can only serve the latter. There’s no way, `forEach` can work without side effects, so it doesn’t work with immutable data. Besides that, this question’s operation is a good example where trying to shoehorn everything into this new lambda world will lead to. The reasonable solution would be `boolean flag = !list.contains("test3"); String cCN = flag? "": "test3";` People coding what is effectively a linear search, instead of letting the collection doing the work is a huge step backwards.

Comment: @Holger I agree that the question doesn't require `forEach`. My comment was regarding claiming that `forEach` has a much more limited area of usage than the truth. While using `contains` provides one solution, it's also very possible to achieve the same result with `list.stream().filter("test3"::equals).findFirst()` and extract `flag` and `cCN` as needed. I wouldn't fault anyone for either way of achieving the result. And that's the point - using streams, functional interfaces and higher level functional code is fine and can be for some (subjectively) be more readable.

Comment: @ODDminus1 but the idiomatic `findFirst()` solution is yet another indicator that `forEach` is not the right tool here. In a lot of cases, `forEach` on a collection is just a loop in disguise, not more FP than the equivalent loop. Besides that, as said, a stream operation is a linear search. Doesn’t matter much if the source is a list whose `contains` implementation does a linear search anyway, but there are collections, like Set, where not using `contains` when applicable, is a waste of resources.

Comment: @Holger I shouldn't need to repeat that I agree that `forEach` is not an appropriate solution to the given question. But it can be useful as a code style for other cases, which is what this answer is heavily arguing against. Yes, it is just a loop in disguise, but that's not the point. The point is that it's a built-in tool which has applications which is okay to prefer over writing the native loop. Regarding the `contains`-solution vs `findFirst`: If it's a huge set, you should of course not stream it. But if you can't spare the resources to stream a list, maybe Java isn't the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use streams?  There are less verbose ways to achieve the same end.

```
int k = list.indexOf("test3");
String ccn = (k >= 0 ? list[k] : "");
```

Comment: No, I am just learning streams, and wanted to understand right way to achieve my use case using lambda or streams.

Comment: Oh, ok. "Educational reasons" make a perfectly fine rationale.

Comment: Or even simpler `String ccn = list.contains("test3")? "test3": "";`